# Installing Dart SDK on Synology DiskStation

Tags: sdk, dart, synology

Has anyone ever tried to install the Dart SDK (http://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk/) on a Synology DiskStation?

I've unzipped the SDK on my DS413, set the PATH variable to the `/bin`-directory, but a `dart -print-flags` results in: `./bin/dart: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what a DiskStation is. But have you tried it locally?

Comment: Oh, I assumed, that it's generally known. Sorry for that. It's a NAS Server (Network-Attached Storage), http://www.synology.com/products/product.php?product_name=DS413&lang=enu, with a Linux-based operating system. The SDK works well on my local machine (Ubuntu 12.10).

Answer (score 0):

Even though the Synology DiskStations are unix based systems, they use a wide range of different processors and thus different architectures. Thus the builds that come for the IA32 and x64 architecture won't work on these diskstations, except you got the right processor with a matching architecture.

You can check the architecture of your diskstation's processor in the [Synology Wiki](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/What_kind_of_CPU_does_my_NAS_have).
All Intel i-Processor should at least work.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to do it inside a Docker container. It's pre-installed on the Synology models that support it.

"google/dart-runtime is a docker base image that makes it easy to dockerize a standard Dart application.

It can automatically bundle a Dart application and its dependencies with a single line Dockerfile."

https://hub.docker.com/r/google/dart-runtime/